# Android ImageButton interaction

Tags: android-xml, android

I wish to create the same activity like in google fit

[image]

And I created an activity with `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ddd"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:onClick="onPreferencesClick"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_grey600_24dp" />
```

But when I click on three dots `button` it doesn't have any push effect in ui, but `onPreferencesClick` works fine.
How to create pushable `ImageButton`?

Comment: Create custom selector for ImageButton : http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a custom selector, for example like this (drawable xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="#33000000"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

and apply it to the background of ImageButton